# error de precision al dividir un double/2.0 en c++

Tags: c++, double, division

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  double x=28423.3;
  double y=x/2.0;
  cout<<y;
}
```

Al divir un número double entre 2 no me da la precisión que necesito y me da de resultado 14211.7 en vez de 14211.65, como podría solucionarlo?
Ya probe a cambiar el compilador, a cambiar de double a float y a long double, a dividir por 2 en vez de por 2.0; y si divido por tres por ejemplo solo me saca 2 decimales en vez de todos los que tenia que sacarme. Al hacer otras divisiones como 2/3 me lo saca con 4 decimales. Muchas gracias

Comment: Mi problema no es que no sea preciso sino que me redondea de más, pero gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: ¿ Que diferencia hay entre *redondear de mas* y *no ser preciso* ?

Comment: lo que mandaste era sobre todo por que al sumar dos decimales como 0.1 + 0.1 te añadian números al final de todo por la suma binaria del ordenador, pero en mi caso el problemas es que me redondea al decimal,

Comment: `cout << std::setprecision( 51 ) << y;`. [Documentado aquí](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Comment: Oh, eso me lo soluciona todo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

> Al divir un número double entre 2 no me da la precisión que necesito

Eso no es cierto. El número se divide correctamente, el problema es que **el resultado se imprime redondeado**. Puedes controlar la precisión con la que se imprimen los números mediante [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision), este código:

```
double x = 28423.3;
double y = x / 2.0;

for (int precision = 0; precision != 20; ++precision)
    cout << "Valor con precision " << precision << ' ' << setprecision(precision) << y << '\n';
```

[Muestra la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##TY7NDoIwEITP9ClWPIghogEPJiCP4clLLdU0gW3Tn0RifHbcegCyh818MztZYcxB9Bxf07RVKPrQSWiUdt5KPrRszQaOyrSMKfQwcIXZ/sOS4BS@APkgneFCgvNdzVjS6fDoJbzhCuXlXFZFVc9wJPiGI5TFKUaf2kIWO42VQjmlkfxTvZIbKiGQ5zPasyQROnhoGkhvvKcKQcHlJI3OIknsaGg56WecLX3RGv@xO@7iV1b6YJH@YN9p@gE):

> ```
> Valor con precision 0 1e+04
> Valor con precision 1 1e+04
> Valor con precision 2 1.4e+04
> Valor con precision 3 1.42e+04
> Valor con precision 4 1.421e+04
> Valor con precision 5 14212
> Valor con precision 6 14211.6
> Valor con precision 7 14211.65
> Valor con precision 8 14211.65
> Valor con precision 9 14211.65
> Valor con precision 10 14211.65
> Valor con precision 11 14211.65
> Valor con precision 12 14211.65
> Valor con precision 13 14211.65
> Valor con precision 14 14211.65
> Valor con precision 15 14211.65
> Valor con precision 16 14211.65
> Valor con precision 17 14211.65
> Valor con precision 18 14211.6499999999996
> Valor con precision 19 14211.64999999999964
> ```